# Laravel homestead can't display Vue js components changes just done inside the code

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vue-component, homestead

This has been crazy. I haven't found some light on this.

I have this laravel test project on homestead where I am using Vue.js. As far as I know, in order to see changes you do in your code, you have to run inside the root directory of your laravel project (inside the Laravel homestead VM) the following command:

`npm run watch`

However, I don't see the changes. For example, if I change in the source code inside the Example.vue file

```
<template>
   <div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component! ... updated 3 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Example Component mounted and updated #1 ....')
        }
    }
</script>
```

in my app.js file I have:

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

And in the blade file:

```
<!-- ... -->
{{--The example component from Example.vue--}}
                            <div id="app">
                                <example></example>
                            </div>
<!-- ... -->
```

I don't see the changes, for example, I just add "update 1", "update 2", and so on to display the changes. npm run watch is running but I don't see any changes on my website, not even by reloading the page ...

So what I do is to stop the npm run watch by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and re run `$ npm run watch` it is where I can finally see the changes i have just typed in the source code.

Something strange to highlight is that changes are shown in Firefox but not in Chrome.

For Chrome, I have tried $ php artisan cache:clear
and reload everything again ... but sometimes it gets update and sometimes it does not.

This is driving me crazy, I also have tried `$ npm run dev`, `$ npm run production` and it's the same. I have to reload and reload ...

I currently have node v8.0.0. and npm 5.1.0

What am I missing to make it watch for changes without having to reload?
Is this vue.js stuff going to be painful as well in a production server?

Comment: try running it locally and not in homestead, any messages in console?

Comment: Any update on this? Im running npm 5.3.0 version. I read a similar problem on this thread: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/933 
which states it is an npm 5.2 issue, has this problem been patched?

Comment: @developerNoob I had to reinstall/update both node and npm globally first, check my references of my blog: [npm installed?](http://pathros.blogspot.com/2017/07/como-saber-si-tengo-instalado-npm-y-si.html) && [Update NodeJS on Mac](http://pathros.blogspot.com/2016/08/actualizar-node-js-en-mac-os-y-con-xampp.html), && [update NodeJS in L-Homestead](http://pathros.blogspot.com/2016/08/como-actualizar-nodejs-en-laravel.html). Moreover, the main trick is that, right after the new Laravel project has been created, you should run `npm install` in your project's root dir and then `npm run dev`|`watch`

Comment: Gracias amigo, I will check out your blog.